# Doubt on showing that when $p$ is prime, the only unipotent class is $p-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand the solution of the following exercise:

> A number $a$ is unipotent if $a\neq1$ and $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.
>
> - Show that when $p$ is prime, the only unipotent class is $p-1$.

The answer is:

> - $(p-1)x\equiv1 \pmod{p}$ has a unique solution in $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. This solution is $x\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. It is the same as $x=p-1$.

I may be doing some very silly mistake: We want to prove that $a=p-1$ is the only number such that $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ but why does the above proof proves it? Aren't we proving only that $a$ is unipotent without - somehow - checking it for $(p-1),(p-2),(p-3),\dots$?

Comment: I can't understand what they are trying to say. Just in case, Wikipedia shows a pretty clear proof (see the beginning of the section): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Mathematical_concepts

Comment: Technically, when $p = 2$ there are no unipotent classes. So this is actually false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly I'm not quite sure what the answer's proof is trying to say, but the easiest way to see this result is to note that $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a field, and thus the polynomial $x^2-1$ can only have at most two roots (i.e., as many roots as its degree). As $x=\pm1$ both solve this polynomial, these are the only roots. As we're excluding $x=1$, this shows that there is a unique unipotent element modulo $p$.

That being said, in the case $p=2$ there are actually no unipotent elements since $1=-1\mod 2$ is the only element that squares to $1$ in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.